# Strange blue border on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

Please, take a look at this code

http://www.jsfiddle.net/tt13/5CxPr/21

On Firefox it shows strange blue border when you select multiple row by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> button but on Chrome it doesn't.

[image]

Using latest Firefox 10.0.2.

Is that browser related bug?

Comment: Isnt that a feature? Firefox highlights selected elements with a blue border.

Comment: It's probably the outline your seeing, try removing it.

Comment: @Alex Dunno. Anyway, if this is feature I want to disable it. Question is, how?

Comment: @adeneo no it's not. tried to add outline:0 to `.selected` selector. Nothing changed

Comment: Hard to say. I can't really test your fiddle, it's not working on Mac. I think the ctrlKey-event isn't fired.

Comment: I haven't test this, but would cancel event bubbling of the CTRL-key help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to text being selected - native browser behavior.

You can observe the same issue in Chrome as well by using the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

To overcome this, you can simply clear the selection right after user click the cell to select:

```
$(".subject").live('click',function(event) {
    if(event.ctrlKey) {
          $(this).toggleClass('selected');  
    } else {
          $(".subject").removeClass("selected");
          $(this).addClass("selected");           
    }
    if (document.selection)
        document.selection.empty();
    else if (window.getSelection)
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CxPr/52/).

Answer (score 8):

Try setting CSS property `-moz-user-select` to the table to disable the default selection behavior:

```
table { -moz-user-select: none; }
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-user-select)

Comment: Negative consequence of this is that it disallows selecting table text at all. Not just removes border on clicking table cell with Ctrl pressed.

Comment: @trl13 solution is to clear the selection, not prevent it - see my answer.

Comment: @trl13 I don't think this native browser feature needs to be fought with at all. It's user's right to be able to use features of his browser. Blocking such features is generally harmful for user experience.

Answer (score 3):

This works for current version of Firefox 20.0.1 if you're prepared to add an extra element inside your cell to allow the text to still be selectable.

```
td { -moz-user-select: -moz-none }
td * { -moz-user-select: text }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nukj7/

Comment: How do you deal with multiple rows?

I have a table with numberous rows. With your solution I just can select one td in one row.

Can you provide a solution?

Thanks in advance