# Remove weird border when ctrl click td in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

When I ctrl+ click on a td, that td will have weird border. It only occur in firefox. Would some one help me with it? Thank you very much.

Here is the live demo http://jsbin.com/banofehisu/edit?html,css,js,output

Just press control and click on the td you'll see it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange blue border on Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451841/strange-blue-border-on-firefox)

Comment: IMO, the best solution in [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451841/strange-blue-border-on-firefox) is [Dale's one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16357590/3702797) but you'll have to wrap all your text content in elements in order to get it working : http://jsfiddle.net/7trk6jqb/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this line:

```
*{
  -moz-user-select: none;
}
```

Or, you may just apply this rule in table.

As per @tushar comment, if you want your text still be selected then you may use jquery like this:

```
$('table').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: This will make the text unselectable

Comment: @Tushar it just prevents the ctrl click but if op wants his own function then OP can insert inside that.

Comment: as mentioned by Tushar, The css code will block text selection, I would add that it will on the whole document while a simple `td` selector instead of the `*` would limit this really bad workaround. Also your js workaround won't work for mac devices (it's  `[cmd]` click on this system) and will block normal behaviour of every anchor contained in any `<table>` in the document.

Comment: @Bhojendra: Yeah, your suggestion is worked.

Thank every body who try to helping me.

Comment: the preventDefault did nothing for me

Comment: @Mojimi that is because `preventDefault` is called afterwards the blue border is displayed.